# Unable to locate packages windows 10 themes and search of packages in site shows no result?

Tags: package-management, software-installation, themes

I installed Ubuntu 17.04 and tried adding Windows 10 theme. The first two commands worked fine but the last `sudo apt-get install windows-10-themes` returned "`unable to locate the package`. How can I solve this problem? Same case for installing UKUI desktop.

These packages are unavailable in Ubuntu packages domain.

Comment: Please include a link to the guide you are following.

Comment: did the answer worked?

Answer (score 2):

Windows 10 GTK Theme, here you go :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/themes
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install windos-10-themes
```

[image: windows 10 theme]

[image: windows 10 theme]

[image: windows 10 theme]

---

See [Noobslab](http://www.noobslab.com/2015/09/do-you-like-windows-10-look-but-love.html) & [Gnome Look](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Windows+10+Theme?content=171327) for more information.